# In OpenCV can you have a weight per pixel with addWeighted?

Tags: python, opencv, blending

I'm trying to blend two images in OpenCV using cv2.addweighted() but I would like to specify a different alpha weight for each pixel instead of one weight for all the pixels. Is it possible to do this in OpenCV or do I have to write my own, slow function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`cv::MatExpr::mul()` function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mul) (Python equivalent) to write something like:

```
cv::Mat C = A.mul(W1) + B.mul(W2);
```

Comment: not sure about python, but in C++ you would have weights and image to have the same element format, which typically includes converts and channel splitting/combining operations, which is very annoying.

Comment: @Micka: True. If `W1` and `W2 are single channel and `A` and `B` are, say, 3-channels, you would need to convert the `W`s to the same format.